# Get return value for multi-processing functions in python

Tags: python, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I have two functions to run in parallel and each of them returns a value. I need to wait for both functions to finish and then process the returns from them. How could I achieve this in python. Assume

```
def fun1():
   #do some calculation#
   return val1

def fun2():
   #do some calculation#
   return val2
```

I want fun1 and fun2 to run in parallel and then need to calculate

```
valsum = val1+val2
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using `concurrent.futures`:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as Executor
#from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as Executor  # to use threads
with Executor() as executor:
    future1 = executor.submit(fun1, arg1, arg2, ...)
    future2 = executor.submit(fun2, arg1, arg2, ...)
    val1, val2 = future1.result(), future2.result()
    valsum = val1 + val2
```

[`concurrent.futures.Executor.submit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit) schedules the function to be executed, and returns a [`concurrent.futures.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) object.

[`concurrent.futures.Future.result`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.result)returns the return value returned by the function.

---

Using [`multiprocessing.pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers):

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
#from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool  # to use threads
with multiprocessing.pool.Pool() as pool:
    result1 = pool.apply_async(fun1, (arg1, arg2, ...))
    result2 = pool.apply_async(fun2, (arg1, arg2, ...))
    val1, val2 = result1.get(), result2.get()
    valsum = val1 + val2
```

[`multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async) returns an `AsyncResult` object, and 
[`AsyncResult.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.get) will return the return value of the function once it finish and the result arrive.

Comment: Using concurrent.futures works fine but not when using multiprocessing.pool. It gives an error that says AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children when using the latter method.

Comment: @TheStupidOne, It works fine for me. Could you show the full traceback?

Comment: The cleanest answer that I've seen in many places Most of the examples work with .map(), but that is not the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example using list comprehension and calling .result() on each future which blocks until the process returns:

```
import concurrent.futures

def download_video(data):
    # print(data) 
    return data

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(download_video, x, ) for x in your_list]
    results = [result.result() for result in futures]
```